# How to save multiple files with different file names in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, save

I want to save each file with a different file name. I know how to do it for individual files as follows:

```
nib.Nifti1Image(wt, affine).to_filename(os.path.join(output_dir, data_file.root.subject_ids[data_index].decode()+"_unc_whole.nii.gz"))
nib.Nifti1Image(tc, affine).to_filename(os.path.join(output_dir,data_file.root.subject_ids[data_index].decode()+ "_unc_core.nii.gz"))
nib.Nifti1Image(et, affine).to_filename(os.path.join(output_dir,data_file.root.subject_ids[data_index].decode()+ "_unc_enhance.nii.gz")) 
nib.Nifti1Image(alea, affine).to_filename(os.path.join(output_dir, data_file.root.subject_ids[data_index].decode()+"_alea.nii.gz"))
```

How can I do this with a for loop so that I don't have to repeat the function for each individual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution, you could use `zip`:

```
alist = [wt, tc, et, alea]
blist = ["_unc_whole.nii.gz", "_unc_core.nii.gz", "_unc_enhance.nii.gz", "_alea.nii.gz"]

for a, b in zip(alist, blist):
    nib.Nifti1Image(a, affine).to_filename(os.path.join(output_dir, data_file.root.subject_ids[data_index].decode() + b))
```